# Erro, Soma de valores em uma JTable

Tags: java, jtable

Boa noite pessoal, estou tentando implementar uma metodo que soma os valores das linhas de uma `JTable`, mas está sempre retornando 0...

Segue meu Codigo.

```
    private void loadData() {
    List<ValoresEntity> list = this.mValoresBusiness.getList();

    String[] columnNames = {"Nome", "Valor de Entrada", "Valor de Repetição", "Id"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[0][0], columnNames);

    for (ValoresEntity valoresEntity : list) {

        Object[] o = new Object[4];
        o[0] = valoresEntity.getName();
        o[1] = valoresEntity.getValue();
        o[2] = valoresEntity.getValuefinal();
        o[3] = valoresEntity.getId();

        model.addRow(o);
        atualizarSaldo();

    }

    this.tableValores.clearSelection();
    this.tableValores.setModel(model);

    this.tableValores.removeColumn(this.tableValores.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));


}

public void atualizarSaldo(){

    double Rsoma = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.tableValores.getRowCount(); i++){

        Rsoma += Double.parseDouble(this.tableValores.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());

    }
    labelAValue.setText("R$" + Rsoma);

    }
}
```

Comment: O código que você postou estava com um erro de quebra de linha, creio que tenha sido ao copiar colar aqui no SO, mas não custa conferir

Comment: Oi, sim, foi ao copiar e colar, fiz um teste agora, e criei um botão pra fazer a soma, e funciona normalmente..., acredito que o erro está na parte que eu aciono o "atualizarSaldo()";

Comment: Consegui resolver, obrigado pela atenção :D

Comment: Não faz sentido você chamar a `atualizarSaldo()` dentro do for toda vez que adicionaro uma linha. Chame somente uma vez após o laço terminar.

Comment: que bom. Crie uma resposta mostrando como você fez para resolver e poste aqui. Vai ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

Então pessoal, pra quem está com o mesmo problema...
Eu resolvi chamando a função "atualizarSaldo();" no meu Public Main(), antes disso eu estava tentando chamar ele assim que eu adicionava uma linha...
Vou deixar o Cod todo aqui, para podermos entender melhor.

```
public Main() {
    this.setContentPane(rootPanel);
    this.setSize(800, 450);
    this.setTitle("Controle de Digitação (Rodrigo Alves v1.0)");

    this.mValoresBusiness = new ValoresBusiness();

    super.defaultConfiguration();

    this.setEvents();

    buttonNew.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);

    this.loadData();
    atualizarSaldo(); // Resolvi chamando ele aqui.
}

private void setEvents() {
    this.buttonNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Valores();
            dispose();
        }
    });

    this.buttonRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO
        }
    });

    this.buttonEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO
        }
    });
}

private void loadData() {
    List<ValoresEntity> list = this.mValoresBusiness.getList();

    String[] columnNames = {"Nome", "Valor de Entrada", "Valor de Repetição", "Id"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[0][0], columnNames);

    for (ValoresEntity valoresEntity : list) {

        Object[] o = new Object[4];
        o[0] = valoresEntity.getName();
        o[1] = valoresEntity.getValue();
        o[2] = valoresEntity.getValuefinal();
        o[3] = valoresEntity.getId();

        model.addRow(o);
        // Eu estava chamando ele aqui.

    }

    this.tableValores.clearSelection();
    this.tableValores.setModel(model);

    this.tableValores.removeColumn(this.tableValores.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));

}

public void atualizarSaldo(){

    double Rsoma = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < this.tableValores.getRowCount(); i++)
        Rsoma += Double.parseDouble(this.tableValores.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
    labelAValue.setText("R$" + Rsoma);
}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado :)